# How to use a do while loop in this situation for C#?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

```
static void Main()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please Input the type of coffee you want! Your options are small, medium, or large!");

  double coffeeprice = 0;
  string coffeechoice = Console.ReadLine();

  switch (coffeechoice.ToUpper())
  {
    case "SMALL":
      coffeeprice += 2.00;
      break;
    case "MEDIUM":
      coffeeprice += 4.00;
      break;
    case "LARGE":
      coffeeprice += 6.00;
      break;

  }
  Console.WriteLine("Generating receipt for your {0} order now!", coffeechoice);
 }
}
```

Yes I know the code isn't well written etc etc. I know there are better ways I can do this but I'm literally a drop dead beginner. All I want to know is where and how I would put a while loop or do while loop into this statement to loop me back to the beginning if I put an invalid statement like if I put HJFRJKLHRKLKEJS instead of small, medium or large.

Comment: you'd put it around the whole block of code you shown (the `while(..) { ` part in the beginning and a closing `}` at the end) - and you'll have o decide on a loop condition (when to end the loop)

Comment: This could be a good question, but it would work much better if you *try* to write that do/while loop with your code.  If it doesn't work, or if it errors out, we'll then be in a much better position to offer guidance.

Comment: There's also a mistake in your business logic. You should default to LARGE on any input other than SMALL or MEDIUM. Marketing 101 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Whelp I found the answer!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Input the type of coffee you want! Your options are small, medium, or large!");

        double coffeeprice = 0;

        string coffeechoice = Console.ReadLine();
        do
        {
            switch (coffeechoice.ToUpper())
            {
                case "SMALL":
                    coffeeprice += 2.00;
                    break;
                case "MEDIUM":
                    coffeeprice += 4.00;
                    break;
                case "LARGE":
                    coffeeprice += 6.00;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input please try again!");
                    coffeechoice = Console.ReadLine();
                    break;

            }
        } while (coffeechoice.ToUpper() != "SMALL" && coffeechoice.ToUpper() != "MEDIUM" && coffeechoice.ToUpper() != "LARGE");




        Console.WriteLine("Generating receipt for your {0} order now!", coffeechoice);
    }

}
```

Turns out all I had to do was declare coffeechoice as Console.ReadLine(); again so it could exist out of context!

Comment: I have another version of the answer - will share now.

Answer (score 1):

You already answered your own question, but here's another way. You already noticed you need to fix your variable scope. Here's another termination condition for you. I used a match against the price since you start at zero and only set the price upon receiving valid input.

```
//initialize coffeechoice to have it in scope at the end when you need it after the loop
string coffeechoice = "";
double coffeeprice = 0;

do {
    Console.WriteLine("Please Input the type of coffee you want! Your options are small, medium, or large!");
    coffeechoice = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (coffeechoice.ToUpper()) {
        case "SMALL":
            coffeeprice = 2.00;
            break;
        case "MEDIUM":
            coffeeprice = 4.00;
            break;
        case "LARGE":
            coffeeprice = 6.00;
            break;
    }
} while (coffeeprice == 0); //price not set, no valid input accepted

Console.WriteLine("Generating receipt for your {0} order now!", coffeechoice);
Console.WriteLine("You paid {0}", coffeeprice);
```

Put this inside your main method and give it a try!

Comment: Wow! I really like the way you solved this as well! Or you could have used string.empty aswell! Either way you have earned one virtual chocolate chip cookie from me :D

Comment: @MattJones If you feel your question is answered, click the check mark icon. You may accept your own answer as well - I believe it will even grant you a badge your first time.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need a while look here: You can define a Case "Default" and ask for input again in case the input is not any of those 3 cases. To define default case you can do following:

```
default:
    Console.WriteLine("Please Input the type of coffee you want! Your options are small, medium, or               large!");    
string coffeechoice = Console.ReadLine();
    break;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Compiler error: A local variable named "coffeechoice' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to "coffee choice". Also that wouldn't work I want it to loop back to the beginning for it to be put in again!

Answer (score -1):

You could use a variable that indicates whether the input was valid or not (like below). While it is possible to check for coffeeprice == 0, I don't prefer that approach because it is not explicit regarding the input and changes in the pricing might require changes to this logic as well.

Also, I am not sure why you want to only loop if the input is invalid because that makes the coffeeprice += unnecessary.

```
bool isInputValid = false;
double coffeeprice = 0;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Input the type of coffee you want! Your options are small, medium, or large!");

    string coffeechoice = Console.ReadLine();
    isInputValid = true;
    switch (coffeechoice.ToUpper())
    {
        case "SMALL":
            coffeeprice += 2.00;
            break;
        case "MEDIUM":
            coffeeprice += 4.00;
            break;
        case "LARGE":
            coffeeprice += 6.00;
            break;
        default:
            isInputValid = false;
            break;
    }
}while (isInputValid == false);

Console.WriteLine("Generating receipt for your {0} order now!", coffeechoice);
```

Comment: Is there any way I can just insert a simple while loop without having to declare a boolean? Also I want it to say "ERROR INVALID INPUT!" And then loop. Also you've declared is input valid as false and leaving the user no choice to put in what he/she wants because its always declared as false. All I want is a simple program that if you don't put in the 3 options it says invalid input and loops back to the beginning. Also the compiler gives me errors from your code! And also you've declared coffee choice inside the do meaning it doesn't exist in context with the last line.

Comment: Throws error "The name 'coffeechoice' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score -1):

Your code would be like this

**UPDATED:**

```
double coffeprice=0;
do
{
Console.WriteLine("Enter you choice:");
string coffeechoice = Console.ReadLine();
switch (coffeechoice.ToUpper())
    {
        case "SMALL":
            coffeeprice += 2.00;
            break;
        case "MEDIUM":
            coffeeprice += 4.00;
            break;
        case "LARGE":
            coffeeprice += 6.00;
            break;

    }
}
while(coffeprice>0);
```

Comment: This does not compile

Comment: I said like this....
I just give you idea if you can't compile, tell me I will do it for you :)